# "Active" class on navigation for belongs_to models in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently generating my header navigation by getting all the objects in the model:

**_header.html.erb**:

```
<% @productlines.each do |productline| %>
        <li class="<%= productline.slug %>"><%= link_to(productline) do %><%= productline.name %><% end %></li>
        <% end %>
```

What this renders in the DOM is this:

```
<ul>
        <li class="pole"><a href="/productlines/pole">pole</a></li>
        <li class="stew"><a href="/productlines/stew">Stew</a></li>
    </ul>
```

My question is: In CSS, how do I apply an "active" class on to the `<li>` so it renders as `<li class="fish active"> ... </li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
<% @productlines.each do |productline| %>
  <li class="<%= productline.slug %> <%= 'active' if productline.slug == 'fish' %>">
    <%= link_to(productline.name, productline) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Just change the condition if you want to add the 'active' class in a different way.

I assume that you want to add an active class when the user is currently on this page - I wrote a helper method (ApplicationHelper) for that:

```
def active?(id)
  return '' unless params[:id] # check for nil
  params[:id].include?(id) ? 'active' : ''
end
```

Then use it like this in your view:

```
<li class="<%= productline.slug %> <%= active?(productline.slug) %>">
```

Comment: The issue is that 'fish' isn't static. I need it to be something like `<%= 'active' if productline.slug == current_url %>`

Comment: I assumed that ;) you can use a param for checking / I don't now how your route -- I am going to update my answer!

Comment: My route is http://localhost:3000/productlines/fish - how would I select just 'fish' from that URL?

Comment: how does your routes.rb define this route?

Comment: `resources :productlines`

Comment: ah so 'fish' is your ``params[:id]``  ?

Comment: `productline = Productline.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82738/discussion-between-beaconhill-and-betty-st).

Comment: I'm getting an error: `undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass` when I'm not on a Productlines page